# Received rep twice for the same edit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, edits

Originally posted on physics.stackexchange: [Received rep twice for the same edit](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9045/received-rep-twice-for-the-same-edit)

As stated there, I received rep twice for a single [edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/142059) to a [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/272893/could-a-candle-theoretically-melt-iron). Both instances of rep happened in the same minute. Not a big deal, but seems to be a bug of some sort.

[image]

(Note: although the screenshot says "today", this happened several days ago. I waited a few days to post about it here as per recommendation of a commenter on physics.se)

Comment: @hichris123 no. That other one was indeed a +4 for same edit, this one here is simple case of suggesting two different edits.

Comment: Ah, yep @ShadowWizard, I didn't double check. Should've smelled that it was different. Retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a closer look at the post links there. :)

You proposed two edits - one on the question and one on an answer. They happened to be approved within seconds of each other.

(As a side note, there's no need to copy bug reports on MSE. Individual site metas are fine. If there's an issue that isn't getting addressed, feel free to flag it for moderator attention and ask a mod to get in touch with a community manager or a dev. Thanks!)